# Aqua button in CSS multiple browsers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an aqua themed button that looks great across multiple browsers. I am new to CSS,  so please be kind.

I have found an example on-line that looks great in Chrome... But does not show up in IE...

Below is the button in chrome...

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="button aqua">
                <div class="glare"></div>
                Button Label
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
  width: 120px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 5px 16px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;

  /* Label */
  font-family: Lucida Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5) 1px 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.aqua{
  background-color: rgba(60, 132, 198, 0.8);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 90%, from(rgba(28, 91, 155, 0.8)), to(rgba(108, 191, 255, .9)));
  border-top-color: #8ba2c1;
  border-right-color: #5890bf;
  border-bottom-color: #4f93ca;
  border-left-color: #768fa5;   
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(66, 140, 240, 0.5) 0px 10px 16px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(66, 140, 240, 0.5) 0px 10px 16px; /* FF 3.5+ */
}

.button .glare {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 142px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 95%, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
}
```

Comment: You are missing css attributes for IE browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing css attributes for IE browser. 
ADD the following.  SAMPLE BELOW.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j67nkxoo/)

```
border-radius:8px;
box-shadow: rgba(66, 140, 240, 0.5) 0px 10px 16px;
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to JSFIDDLE. I have been recompiling my web project every time to see my CSS changes. As good as Visual Studio is this is much better

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not recognize `-webkit` or `-moz` browser prefixes. Everywhere you see those, also add the same attribute without the prefix.

For example:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(66, 140, 240, 0.5) 0px 10px 16px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(66, 140, 240, 0.5) 0px 10px 16px;
```

Add:

```
box-shadow: rgba(66, 140, 240, 0.5) 0px 10px 16px;
```

And, just FYI, `-webkit` is for Chrome/Safari and `-moz` is for Firefox.